# Does every group whose order is a power of a prime p contain an element of order p?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I need to know if every group whose order is a power of a prime $p$ contains an element of order $p$? Should I proceed by picking an element $g$ of the group and proving that there is an element in $\langle g \rangle$ that has order $p$?

Comment: I think you have just proven the statement, if you add that $g$ is non-trivial. :P

Comment: Cauchy says the answer is "oui".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are some results that are much stronger than that. [Cauchy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) states that every finite group whose order is divisible by some prime $p$ has a subgroup of order $p$. And from [Sylow's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems) it can be deduced (although not immediately) that if the order of the group is $p^n$ then there is one subgroup of order $p^k$ for every $k=0,1,..,n$.

One more thing, a subgroup of order $p$ must be cyclic, that is, there has to be an element of order $p$ in it. That is because by Langrange's theorem the order of every element must divide the $p$ and since it is prime then the order must be $1$ or $p$. Any element different from the identity will do the trick.

*Note*: Lagrange's theorem alone is not enough to prove this since it only states that if the order of the group is $p^n$ then every subgroup is of the form $p^k$. That is because what Lagrange's theorem says is that the order of every subgroup must divide the order of the group. So you actually need a little bit more I think.

*Late note due to nice comments*: While the result doesn't follow directly from Lagrange's theorem statement. It *can be derived* from it as it is nicely shown to you in other answers. So you actually can avoid appealing to a stronger result such as Cauchy's theorem since you are in a finite $p$-group (what I mean by saying that it doesn't follow directly is that Lagrange's theorem makes no reference to $p$-groups, so there is math involved).

Comment: Lagrange actually suffices for this weaker problem, as $ord(gcd(y^d)=\frac{ord(y)}{GCD(ord(y), d)}$.

Comment: Your note at the end points out a problem in using Lagrange for arbitrary groups, but not for groups of prime-power order (as the other answers make clear).

Comment: Nice comments. I added a second note.

Answer (score 19):

This follows immediately from Lagrange theorem, you don't need any stronger result.

If the order of the group is $p^k$ with $k \neq 0$, then by Lagrange Theorem, the order of any element divides $p^k$.

Pick some $x \in G, x \neq e$. Then the order of $x$ is $p^m$ with $1 \leq m \leq k$. Let

$$y:=x^{p^{m-1}} \,.$$

Prove that the order of $y$ is $p$.

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks.

Comment: @Hopmaths What do you mean? If $x \in G$ and $G$ is closed under multiplication (which is always true for a group) then  $x^{p^{m-1}} \in G$. I am not using at any point any reciprocal of Lagrange.

Comment: @Hopmaths You have to be careful $x^{p^m}=e$ does not mean that the order is $p^m$, it could be smaller. It only means $ord(x)|p^m$. So call the order of $G$ $p^k$. If $x\neq e$ you know that $ord(x) |p^k$. This means there exists some $1 \leq m \leq k$ such that $ord(x)=p^m$. Now, an easy computation (which you must do) shows that $ord(x^{p^{m-1}})=p$

Comment: For the last step show that $y^p=e$. This means $ord(y)$ divides $p$. What does this mean?

Comment: @Hopmaths You need to show that $y \neq e$ not that $x \neq e$!

Answer (score 8):

Not the group of order $p^0=1$!

Other than that, first prove that if the order of a group element $x$ is $mn$, then the order of $x^m$ is $n$.  Then you can either show directly that if $x\in G$ and $|G|$ is finite, $x^{|G|}$ is the identity, or apply Lagrange's theorem to $\langle x \rangle$.

Comment: p^0 \ne 0-- it's 1.

Comment: @FernandoPessoa Whoops, thanks.